# which web framework gives more functionality for free?

Tags: language-agnostic, web-frameworks

I'm using codeigniter for a little time and I find it really good, but sometimes it's difficult to find pre-cooked examples on the web that will guide me on what I want to do...so my question is which web framework(independent of language) will offer more examples, better tutorials and more resources in general?thanks in advance

Comment: that is really impossible to answer in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this wikipedia comparison of frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks) to see what they support out of the box (resources).

As to user base / documentation / useful examples: it depends on code that you can easily read as well. Have a look at:

http://static.raibledesigns.com/repository/presentations/WebFrameworksOfTheFuture-FlexGWTRailsAndGrails.pdf and https://equinox.dev.java.net/framework-comparison/WebFrameworks.pdf also compare frameworks.

I personally use the MS family, and I am satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) , it has alot of examples and really nice documentation.
It has a very nice way in handling models relationships

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you have a look at the following, categorized in no particular order, with their language of implementation and support in brackets. They all present rather clean and novative aspects, but I don't think there's any real silver bullets. Just lots of very nice bullets depending on what you aim for.

### The Laureates are...

- [Lift](http://www.liftweb.net/) ([Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), [Java](http://java.oracle.com/))
- [Play](http://www.playframework.org/) ([Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), [Java](http://java.oracle.com/))
- [SeaSide](http://www.seaside.st/) ([Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk))
- [Ruby on Rails](http://www.rubyonrails.org/) ([Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/))
- [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) ([Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), [Java](http://java.oracle.com/))
- [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) ([PHP](http://www.php.net/))
- [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) ([Java](http://java.oracle.com/))

### Others

There are other ones, but these were the ones that struck me a blow the first time I saw and experimented with them, and which have - in my opinion - brought some innovation to the scene in general or to their platform in particular.

Note that this isn't to say that some other frameworks may have been equally significant, but I merely list relatively recent and modern ones, and most importantly ones that I will still consider to write a modern web-app (in the general case).

Feel free to look around for more (and maybe add them in comments or edit this answer).

### A few notes...

Play is indeed fun to poke around. Yii is the only PHP framework I'd touch with a very long pole (maybe CodeIgniter as well, granted, but I find Yii cooler and less of a hurdle to use and to work through). Rails/Grails are obviously on par. Wicket is something you'd want to consider if you are in a Java shop that's relatively restrictive and doesn't want anything ultra-exotic, but still enough on the edge.

**But mostly, I'd recommend you have a look at Lift and Seaside**, if you want to see something truly amazingly well thoughout and for the highest feature-per-LOC ratio. (Oh, and it's inspired partly by Seaside and Wicket, and designed by someone who had to work with a lot of (g)rails web-apps, so that sums it up. Plus Scala is an amazing language, granted you can use it and its underlying platform...)

*This is an old question, but what the hell, Just came across it...*